# How to tell whether my firebase node is used?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Firebase offers some overall Analytics in their App Dashboard, however, I need to know whether my stored data are ever used or they are just lying idly on a **per node basis**.

Why? It's simple: we are learning while developing, which makes the app a very fast evolving one. Not only the logic changes, but also the data stored need to be refactored from time to time. I would like to get rid of abandoned and forgotten data. Any ideas?

> ### In best case, I would like to know this:
>
> 1. When was a node used last time? (was it used at all?)
> 2. How many times was it used in 1h/24h/1w/1M?
> 3. Differentiate between read/write operations

Comment: Firebase doesn't keep track of this, so you'll have to write the necessary logic yourself. Unless you've already done some of the legwork involved with that, this question is a bit too broad.

Comment: Now that I think of it, the reading really actually depends on what nodes I set my listeners to. I can easily set a listener to a root node, which will return the whole data structure and mark it as read even though I am only using a single value from it. So.. Is it possible to see a list of paths registered to listen for in an app? But then.. It gets quite complicated the more I think about it as we also have `once` or already unregistered listeners.

Comment: It would be quite simple to add updated counters or update timestamps to any records. Security rules can enforce that clients update/set these to a current timestamp whenever they are updated. Nothing built into Firebase will do this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 2017 update

**Cloud Functions** trigger automatically and run on server.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/
https://howtofirebase.com/firebase-cloud-functions-753935e80323

---

### 2016 answer

So apparently the Firebase itself doesn't provide any of this.

The only way I can think of right now is to create wrappers for firebase query and write functions and either do the statistics in a client app or create a devoted node for storing the statistical data.

In case of storing the data in firebase, the wrapper for writing functions (`set`, `update`, `push`, `remove`, `setWithPriority`) is relatively easy. The query functions (`on`, `once`) will have to write in a `successCallback`.